# How to capture OutputDebugString messages

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, sysinternals

I have an application written in [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions) which uses OutputDebugString() ([Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) API) to log messages. The output is a DLL file. Are there ways or a utility that can capture these messages?

Comment: Whats up with the sysinternals one? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: Is there something wrong with the Visual Studio output window?